# (BATCH) Multiple colors on one line

Tags: batch-file

i'm wondering if there's a way to use multiple colors on one line of text (for example: "Hello world" when "Hello" is Blue and "world" is green.

I'm sorry for asking this stupid question in the first place... I was doing a ton of research and some of them didnt work out properly and i was hoping for easier ways to get what I wanted. Sorry guys =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Echo Off
Call :Color 9 "hello" 

Call :Color A " world"

Pause >Nul
Exit /B


:Color
:: v20  by carlos.
:: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4453
:: Arguments: hexColor text [\n]
:: Supported in windows XP, 7, 8.
:: In XP extended ascii characters are printed as dots.
:: For print quotes, use empty text.
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Text=%~2"
If Not Defined Text (Set Text=^")
Subst `: "!Temp!" >Nul &`: &Cd \
If Not Exist `.7 (
Echo(|(Pause >Nul &Findstr "^" >`)
Set /P "=." >>` <Nul
For /F "delims=;" %%# In (
'"Prompt $H;&For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do (
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.3
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.5
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.7))
Set /P "LF=" <` &Set "LF=!LF:~0,1!"
For %%# in ("!LF!") Do For %%_ In (
\ / :) Do Set "Text=!Text:%%_=%%~#%%_%%~#!"
For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# in ("!Text!") Do (
If #==#! SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
If \==%%# (Findstr /A:%~1 . \` Nul
Type `.3) Else If /==%%# (Findstr /A:%~1 . /.\` Nul
Type `.5) Else (Echo %%#\..\`>`.dat
Findstr /F:`.dat /A:%~1 .
Type `.7))
If "\n"=="%~3" (Echo()
Goto :Eof
```

[Here's the color function by carlos](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4453)